# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10

Tags: java, android

Please do not mark this question as duplicate before read. I am new to java and working on one application which I am facing issue of

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
```

When I click on last item of list. I know that my array is like 0-9 and so if I use 10 as number then I am getting error. My code is like below

```
private class Page {

    private int mIndx;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mQuotes;


    private Page(int indx, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> quoteList) {
        mQuotes = quoteList;
        mIndx = indx;
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> getQuote(int indx) {

        return mQuotes.get(indx);

    }
}
```

This function is returning error called above. Now I have tried like this

```
private class Page {
    public static int postion;
    private int mIndx;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mQuotes;
    private Page(int indx, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> quoteList) {
        mQuotes = quoteList;
        mIndx = indx;
    }
    private HashMap<String, String> getQuote(int indx) {

        if(indx == mQuotes.size())
        {
            postion = indx- 1;
        }
        else{
            postion = indx;

        }
        return mQuotes.get(postion);

    }

}
```

This is my get quote method

```
private HashMap<String, String> getQuote(int position) {
    int pageIndx = ((position + 1) / QuotesListFragment.ITEMS_PER_PAGE) + (((position + 1) % QuotesListFragment.ITEMS_PER_PAGE) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    Page page = mQuotePages.get(pageIndx);
    if (page == null) {
        page = loadQuotePage(pageIndx);

    }
    int quoteIndxOfPage = position % QuotesListFragment.ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
    return page.getQuote(quoteIndxOfPage);

}
```

Some More Code if I was missing to add

```
public Cursor getQuotesByPage(int quotesType,String author,int pageIndx,int numOfItems){

        int offset=(pageIndx-1)*numOfItems;

        switch(quotesType){
            case 1:
                return  getQuotes(offset,numOfItems);
            case 2:
                return  getFavoriteQuotes(offset,numOfItems);
            case 3:
                return getAuthorQuotes(author,offset,numOfItems);
            case 4:
                return getAuthorQuotesTopLiked(author, offset, numOfItems);
            case 5:
                return getAuthorQuotesTopShared(author, offset, numOfItems);
            case 6:
                return  getQuotesTopLiked(offset,numOfItems);
            case 7:
                return  getQuotesTopShared(offset,numOfItems);

        }

        return null;

    }


    public Cursor getQuotes(int offset,int limit) {
        // Select All Query


        if (String.valueOf(offset).equals("50000")) {
            String query_count = "SELECT COUNT(" + QU_ID + ") AS count FROM "
                    + TABLE_QUOTES;
            Cursor c_count = database.rawQuery(query_count, null);
            c_count.moveToFirst();
            Integer count = c_count.getInt(c_count.getColumnIndex("count"));
            limit =count;// String.valueOf(count);

        }

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES + " JOIN "
                + TABLE_AUTHORS + " ON " + QU_AUTHOR + " = " + AU_WEB_ID
                + " ORDER BY " + QU_ID + " DESC "+ " LIMIT " + offset+","+limit;
        //Log.i("query",query);

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor;

    }
```

Full log is here

```html
Process: com.karopass.gujarati_status, PID: 6865
                                                                            java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
                                                                                at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                                at com.karopass.gujarati_status.material.QuoteViewActivity$Page.getQuote(QuoteViewActivity.java:703)
                                                                                at com.karopass.gujarati_status.material.QuoteViewActivity$Page.access$1000(QuoteViewActivity.java:690)
                                                                                at com.karopass.gujarati_status.material.QuoteViewActivity.getQuote(QuoteViewActivity.java:653)
                                                                                at com.karopass.gujarati_status.material.QuoteViewActivity.access$800(QuoteViewActivity.java:48)
                                                                                at com.karopass.gujarati_status.material.QuoteViewActivity$QuoteFragmentAdapter.getItem(QuoteViewActivity.java:632)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:109)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1248)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:911)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19965)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2309)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1645)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1280)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6432)
07-12 09:23:54.208 6865-6865/com.karopass.gujarati_status E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

But now its showing my last item two time.... I am wrong in somewhere....Please help me to solve issue....what Can I do for solve this puzzle...I have read many similar question in stackflow but not able to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: How are you calling `getQuote`? Because you only have 10 items. The item at index 10, is the eleventh item. Thus, you are displaying it twice with you second example.

Comment: There's a problem in how you called `getQuote`.  Since you haven't shown us the code that does that, it's hard to help you.

Comment: when you call getQuote(index) make sure , you call only upto mQuotes.size()-1..  and remove indx == mQuotes.size()

Comment: Why do you create private class?

Comment: As your `position` is static `public static int postion;` then this would not be thread safe

Comment: @ajb I have edited and added getQuote Method... Thanks

Comment: @VIX Why not?  We can't see the whole code--possibly this is an inner class?

Comment: @ajb Yes, but not specify in the post.

Comment: @VIX Why does it matter?  It has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: What is `QuotesListFragment.ITEMS_PER_PAGE`?  How is a `Page` constructed?  Does `mQuotesPages.get()` construct the new page, and if so, how?  There's still a lot of code missing that we need to see.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE for information on how to create a _complete_ example that we could run ourselves to see where the problem is.

Comment: @ajb QuotesListFragment.ITEMS_PER_PAGE is int value like 10. Thanks

Comment: @ajb I have added more code....let me know if now its enough....Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Something is not right.  If `ITEMS_PER_PAGE` is 10, then `position % QuotesListFragment.ITEMS_PER_PAGE` would give you a value from 0 to 9.  It's impossible for this expression to be 10.  So how were you getting an exception with your original code, that said `Index: 10, Size: 10`???  Are you sure the exception was on `return mQuotes.get(indx);`?

Comment: In getQoute()  method,  when indx = 9 and when indx = 10,  you will always get 9, hence repeated item.  Assuming tha size is 10. Also there must be a line no against the error in log,  please post a complete log so that it helps us to help you.

Comment: @jackjay I have attached full log...Please check. Thanks

Comment: @ajb sorry Item_per_page is 20. Thanks

Comment: Ahhh, we're getting closer...  So `ITEMS_PER_PAGE` is 20, but your `Page` array only has 10 items in it?  Why is the page shorter than it should be?  Is it because this is the end of the list, so the last page doesn't go all the way to the end?  If that's the case, then `position` is too large, and either the `getQuote` that has a `position` parameter shouldn't be called, or it should make sure `position` is not too large and do something special--but you have to decide what it should do.

Answer (score -1):

If size is 10, then it means you can iterate from 0 - 9 positions. (That makes total 10 elements).

It's printing the last element 2 times because of this ..

> When indx is 9, (points to the last element of the hashmap), it will go in the else condition and return the last element.
>
> Next time when the index will be 10, it will go in the if case and there you are doing **postion = indx- 1;** , that will also return the element on position 9.

Comment: You seem to have come to the conclusion that the index starts at 1.  But look at the code she posted later that calls `getQuote`.  Your conclusion is wrong.

Comment: I haven't looked at that .. BTW i have figured out why it's showing last element 2 times. No she needs to figure out the solution herself. .

Answer (score -2):

> Index: 10, Size: 10

Index enumerates from zero, so when size is 10, then max allowed index is 9, therefore this line:

```
if(indx == mQuotes.size())
```

is wrong as it should be

```
if(indx == mQuotes.size()-1)
```

Comment: Hello sir.....Thanks for your answer....Can You please help me so what should I write there instead of if(indx == mQuotes.size()) ?

Comment: I don't see how this will solve the problem--I think it will just display the next-to-last element twice, instead of the last one.

Comment: The value of indx should be between 0 to 9, and the if-sentence is if(indx == mQuotes.size()-1)

Answer (score -2):

I think you are calling getQuote() function of Page class in some kind of loop so your **index** argument should always have value from 0 to mQuotes.size()-1 then you can simply do below.

```
private HashMap<String, String> getQuote(int indx) { if(indx>= mQuotes.size()) { return null;} else{return mQuotes.get(indx); }}
```

Comment: Why downvote? because some people can answer more swiftly without seeing the whole code. Whoever downvoted please find a better solution for this then without changing the whole code. Thanks

Comment: You have no way of knowing whether returning `null` is an appropriate behavior, in the context of the entire program.  Also, you've assumed that the index has value 1-10, while if you look at the code she posted later you can see that this assumption is wrong.  Swiftness doesn't count if your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @ajb I edited my answer. I am returning null because if indx argument is greater than the size of list then it is going to throw exception and that's what happening in this case.